# AngularJs checkbook true/false options

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS is having a problem:

> Error: [$parse:syntax]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bcampaign.paused%7D%7D&p4=%7Bcampaign.paused%7D%7D
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://localhost/platform/js/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
>       at gb.throwError (http://localhost/platform/js/angular/angular.min.js:190:254)
>       at gb.object (http://localhost/platform/js/angular/angular.min.js:199:435)
>       at gb.primary (http://localhost/platform/js/angular/angular.min.js:189:308)
>       at gb.unary (http://localhost/platform/js/angular/angular.min.js:197:82)
>       at gb.multiplicative (http://localhost/platform/js/angular/angular.min.js:196:324)
>       at gb.additive (http://localhost/platform/js/angular/angular.min.js:196:182)
>       at gb.relational (http://localhost/platform/js/angular/angular.min.js:196:48)
>       at gb.equality (http://localhost/platform/js/angular/angular.min.js:195:418)(anonymous
>   function) @ angular.js:11592b.$get @ angular.js:8542c.$get.l.$digest @
>   angular.js:14241c.$get.l.$apply @ angular.js:14486l @ angular.js:9644O
>   @ angular.js:9834w.onload @ angular.js:9775

The origin is fairly obvious, and when I remove this HTML it goes away

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model={{campaign.paused}} 
 ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'" />
```

$scope.campaign.paused is coming from JSON data which I receive from my server:

```
{
    "campaign_id": "1",
    "paused": "0"
}
```

Question: how do I get my HTML to recognize the 0 or 1 of `paused` as true/false and (un)check the box accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-checked directive with checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked={{campaign.paused}} />
```

Comment: That would work too (+1), but what was wrong with ng-model? I am curios to know f there is a difference. For anyone reading thsi in the future,  the docs for ng-checked are at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the curly brackets in the model:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="campaign.paused" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
```